# Do we need a tag for Keras 2.0?

Tags: discussion

A few weeks ago Keras 2.0 was released. Together with this release it appears that all documentation for Keras 1.2.1 were removed as well.

I am wondering if questions concerning Keras should be tagged with that version?

Rational: With the release of the new version, there were a lot of API changes and new features. E.g.:

- in Keras 1.2.1, you would have this line:

  model.fit(nb_epoch=50)
- in Keras 2.0.0, the keyword has changed to this:

  model.fit(epoch=50)

There are many such examples. Therefore, would it not be good to be able to tag questions related to Keras 2.0 specifically as such? This will reduce confusion for future users of Keras who go here to find answers.

I am asking because I do not currently have the capability of creating a new task. What do other people think?

Comment: A keyword change is enough for a new tag?

Comment: Wait, is it even possible to use the old version still? If it isn't, then everything in that tag which refers to the old version should be updated to the new version or deleted.

Comment: Assume this scenario. Keras 1.2.1 is still in the wild. Up until a few weeks ago, all answers concerning Keras were about Keras 1. Assume, I ask about Keras 1, you have Keras 2 and answer the question based on that version. You see the tag and it says Keras. If you answer based on Keras 2, then we have a miscommunication problem. It's of course always better to mention what version you are on, but I do believe that a tag can also alleviate this. Afterall, we also have a python3 tag (not just only python).

Comment: No, there would not be miscommunication problem: the asker would add which version he's using (if it's relevant), or would comment on the answer saying that it doesn't solve the issue with further analysis.

Comment: I can see it that way as well. My question then is: Why do we have a Python and a python3 tag? Or I guess: What is the criteria by which we determine that something is tag worthy?

Comment: I found the link to keras docs for all versions: https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/  Version 1.2.1, which I need, is https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.1/

Comment: https://blog.keras.io/introducing-keras-2.html  "[for] long term support.., **We have extensively redesigned the API with this release... The API of most layers has significantly changed... The API of generator training & evaluation methods has changed** (i.e. `fit_generator`, `predict_generator`, and `evaluate_generator`)..." While they have made it possible for old code to *mostly* still run on Keras 2, the New API's *won't* work on keras 1.  Since I am stuck on keras 1.2.1 for now, I'm finding a great amount of example code on the web won't compile for me.  It'd be useful to have `keras-1`